# Not clear proposal for input

Tags: input, user-input

"Write a program that reads a sequence of `integers` from **standard input**."

Do they mean read the input from the `command line prompt` or from user?
`Integer.parseInt` or `input.nextInt`(using `scanner`)?

Comment: No, they probably mean [*standard input*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) when they say so

Answer (score 0):

I believe standard input can be the input from command line prompt.